# Book about a girl or woman who has to go to a school for magical beings

Tags: story-identification, books

So this book I'm looking for I think the main character goes to a school or something like that for magical beings.

There's a lot of people who don't like her and like how well she is doing in challenges.

There's one part where they have to pick a stone/gem/jewel from somewhere and this person was bragging about the best stone and how she was going to get it There's like three different types of rare stones that could potentially be picked. And the main character people don't like ends up picking the rarest one.

I feel like they had instructors and they had dorm rooms and maybe she ended up in the male dorm I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  When did you read this?  Do you recall the name of any of the characters or the name of the school?  Do you remember the cover art of the book?